# Glassfish OSGI with dependencies, how to?

Tags: glassfish, dependencies, osgi

I have a regular maven jar project, which has dependencies such as the reflection library and I want to
convert it to osgi, what Ive already done.

1. created a common interface layer in a different (maven) jar
   project and added it to the bundle as a dependencies.
2. changed the type of the osgi-module-to-be to 'bundle'.
3. created an implementation of BundleActivator
4. added this plugin the pom:

```
<groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.3.7</version>
<extensions>true</extensions>
<configuration>
    <instructions>
        <Bundle-Activator>my.package.MyServiceActivator</Bundle-Activator>
        <Export-Package>
            my.package.exp.*
        </Export-Package>
        <Import-Package>
            !org.reflections,???
        </Import-Package>
        <Embed-Dependency>
            slf4j-api;scope=compile,???
        </Embed-Dependency>
    </instructions>
</configuration>
```

here is where it gets lost, I need to figure out the "Import-Package" and "Embed-Dependency"
and, **even more important** figure how to deploy it on glassfish as a zip or, 
maybe, ORB (or Gogo) so that it will deploy with all it's dependencies jars.

any ideas?

G.

BTW: the org.reflections package is not OSGi ready

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're confused about how OSGi and the Maven Bundle plugin work.
Maybe reading the Felix guide will help you:

http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html

Basically, you should have something like this:

```
<plugin>   
  <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
  <extensions>true</extensions>
  <configuration>
    <instructions>
      <Bundle-Activator>my.package.MyServiceActivator</Bundle-Activator>
      <Export-Package>
        my.package.exp.*
      </Export-Package>
      <Import-Package>
        !org.reflections*,*
      </Import-Package>
      <Embed-Dependency>
         org.reflections
      </Embed-Dependency>
    </instructions>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

By default (ie. if you just omit it, which is usually the case), your Import-Package instructions would be `*`, which means anything you refer to in the code which is not in java.* or in your own bundle should be imported. But as you have a dependency on a non-bundle jar you want to embed, you need to tell the plugin that by using the expression `!org.reflections*,*`, which means you don't want to import the org.reflections package but everything else is fine. You also need to declare that any artifactId called `org.reflections` should be embedded in the jar by using the Embed-Dependency instruction.

BTW, You most likely don't want to embed your logging framework SLF4J implementation, let alone the API, as just about any OSGi environment should provide a logging implementation for you.

After you package your bundle (mvn package or just mvn install) make sure to check the generated MANIFEST to ensure that it looks like everything is correct (importantly, check the Import-Package packages and see if your environment will have all bundles which provide such packages).

Once you get your bundle set up correctly, deploying it is trivial. Just drop it into your framework's bundle directory, ensure all other bundles you need are also there, and everything should work fine.

As a side note, you might want to consider wrapping the non-bundle JAR you need as a bundle by using [PAX-WRAP](http://team.ops4j.org/wiki/display/paxurl/Wrap+Protocol) or just Karaf (just throw a JAR in the deploy folder and you will get it wrapped as an OSGi bundle immediately), for example.